# inner join within same table

Tags: mysql

Using a union, select the publisher information for those publishers that live in Boston or Kingston.   Insert your query and results here.

```
 select * from publisher c1,publisher c2
 where publisher.city="Boston" or publisher.city="Kingston"
 and c1.publisher_name=c2.publsiher_name;
```

I'm trying to form something like this above however it's not giving me any results. I need to pull information from the same table but use a union and I'm trying to use an alias as im sure you have to

Only three fields exist in the publisher table: `publisher_name`, `publisher_code`, and `city`

Any idea on how can make it output all the information from publishers but use a union with alias
I know how to do it this way below but I'm trying to understand how to do it with the code above

```
select * from publisher
where city ="Boston" 
union
select * from publisher
where city ="Kingston";
```

Comment: If you give a table an alias, use the alias. (This is a ridiculous use of a UNION - but I guess that's not your fault)

Comment: The first query likely needs the OR clauses wrapped in brackets. Also, there's no "publisher" alias, so you have to specify c1 or c2 when specifying your city columns. However, the two queries you have here will do two different things. Let's say that your UNION query returns 5 rows - this means that your join will also return 5 rows (assuming the publisher_name is unique), but you will have doubled columns (since it is joining the tables). Your second query would be useful to "find publishers that have a row with a city value of Boston, and another row with a value of Kingston".

Comment: Looks like a copy-paste quote from a homework assignment. If it says, "using a  `UNION`" then use the second query.

Comment: Why not "try something first" as a way to learn? There are resources like http://sqlfiddle.com that allow you to quickly build tables and run sql queries (tip look at the Text to DDL button) have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af5c82/1